# Can't import Landsat 4 images to Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat

I am trying to add a *Landsat 4 level 2 collection 2* image to the Google Earth Engine code editor. The code sample is the following.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT04/C02/T1_L2')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 150))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 46))
    .filterDate('1987-01-01', '1995-12-31');
print(dataset)

var image = ee.Image(dataset.sort('CLOUD_COVER').first());
print(image)

Map.setCenter(85.4788, 19.8450, 8);

Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['SR_B3']} , 'B3');
```

But no image is being displayed on the map.
`print(dataset)` shows `ImageCollection LANDSAT/LT04/C02/T1_L2 (0 elements)` and `print(image)` shows `null`.

**Why the image is null. If the answer is, there is no image, how come? I think there should be some images as the search result on the USGS Earth Explorer website shows the images.**
Can someone please explain what is the issue and how to display the images for the 1980s on GEE. I'm also facing the same issues with Landsat 1-3 MSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because that particular collection is empty for your given path row combination and the given date range.

Comment: ok... but how come? for the same conditions, I can find images on USGS Earth Explorer.

Comment: Because of the collection type probably. There is TOA, RAW and SUR information and then these is also T1 versus T2 collection. Most likely what you see on the USGS is T1 collection for L4 or the Landsat 5 (they are aggregated there), so you can try those: 

ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT04/C01/T1_TOA") OR ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA")